# Porting from WPF to Silverlight - ItemsControl/ItemCollection

Tags: wpf, silverlight, itemscontrol, porting, itemcollection

I'm porting an app (which someone else wrote) from WPF to Silverlight. I have a class which inherits from ItemsControl. In part of the code I access the ItemsControl.Items property (of type ItemCollection). However, some of the methods/properties which exist in WPF are missing in Silverlight:

- MoveCurrentToFirst()
- CurrentItem
- CurrentPosition
- GetItemAt()

What is the Silverlight equivalent of these methods/properties, or is there a totally different way of approaching this in Silverlight? My internet searches only return information for WPF, with no information on Silverlight.

any help appreciated.